# Gearman + Net_Gearman + Windows

Tags: php, gearman

I'm trying to install Gearman + Net_Gearman + GearmanManager on a windows machine (2003 server).

At this moment, I executed correctly the java version of the Job Server (java-gearman-service), installed PEAR and the Net_Gearman package.

- Do I need to add gearman library to php.ini? How?
- What is the way to "connect" gearmanmanager to net_gearman? Is it necessary to copy the files of gearmanmanager in the same directory of I thing is net_gearman (C:\php\PEAR\Net\Gearman)?
- How do I test that everything is working fine?

Thanks, I'm really lost with that and work with windows it's a big handicap :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GearmanManager won't work on Windows - so there's not much you can do there. It uses the pcntl extension in PHP, which is not available for Windows.

You do not need to add PHP_Gearman to the ini file, as it's a PEAR library. As long as it's installed as a regular PEAR package (in the directory configured in your php.ini by default), you're good to go. Otherwise you'll have to add the directory containing Net/ to your include_path.

You can test that everything is working fine by submitting a task to a gearman server by running your client from the CLI, and then seeing if your worker process gets any work to do. I don't know anything about the java-gearman-service, but the regular C-daemon can be put into a "more verbose" mode by adding -vvvv to the command line (I forget the number of v-s: more v's equals more verbose.

I know that this is an old question, but if anyone stumbles across this through the intarwebs..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know too much about the PHP version, NET_Gearman, but I'm betting you'll get a faster response at the google group (http://groups.google.com/group/gearman). Given that it is a pure PHP implementation, I'm assuming it'll work under windows.

damn windows...

PS. I'm glad to see people are using the java-gearman-service :).

Comment: Thank you Isaiah, I'll take your advice. I hope I'll be lucky and get a Linux machine so all my problems dissapear :)